# Bedeutung von "ein Argument sticht (nicht)"

Tags: meaning

Was bedeutet der Ausdruck " ein Argument sticht (nicht)" Bspw.

> Darüber hinaus sticht auch das Argument der Bundesregierung nicht mehr,...
>   Dieses Argument sticht selten.

Und woher kommt er?

Comment: Ich kenne "das Argument *zieht* nicht".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Ein Stich* ist ein einzelner Kartenabwurf aller Spieler im *Skat*, *Schafskopf*, usw.

Es gibt in der abschließenden Zählung z.B. beim Skat, wertvolle (Bube, Dame, König, 10, As) und wertlose (7, 8, 9) Karten. Diese wertlosen Karten werden *Luschen* genannt.

Es ist das Ziel des beim Reizen unterlegenen Spielerpaars, dem Einzelspieler trotz dessen Übermacht an *Trümpfen* (Buben und Karten in der Trumpffarbe) den Sieg noch abzunehmen — oder zumindest zu verkleinern, denn beim Skat wird nach Punkten abgerechnet. Dafür hauen die Paarspieler ihre Luschen so geschickt heraus, dass der Einzelspieler möglichst seine höchsten Trümpfe für niedrige Werte und Luschen des Spielerpaares verschwenden muss.

**Trifft ein Stich nicht**, bedeutet es, dass einer der in der Vorhand befindlichen Spieler eine für ihn wertvolle Karte ausgespielt hat, in der Hoffnung, damit eine fast ebenso wertvolle Karte des Gegners erbeuten zu können. Und das hat nicht geklappt. Weil der Gegner immer noch mit einer Lusche antworten konnte.

Mit den nicht stechenden Argumenten ist es wie mit den nicht stechenden Karten. Sie verpuffen wirkungslos.

Answer (score 2):

Wie Janka richtig bemerkt kommt der Ausdruck vom Kartenspielen.

Wer die höchste Karte in einer Runde legt macht den Stich. Eine Karte sticht, wenn sie höher ist als die anderen, aber auch wenn die anderen Luschen abwerfen und auch ob man in der Vorhand ist tut auch nichts zur Sache.

Schwache Karten *stechen selten*, etwa beim Skat eine Nicht-Trumpf-9, aber wenn die anderen nur 7 und 8 haben und bedienen müssen oder keinen Trumpf haben eben doch. Schwache Argumente stechen auch nur selten, aber wenn das Gegenüber rhetorisch unterbelichtet ist, vielleicht doch.

Eine Karte *sticht nicht mehr* könnte man sagen, wenn sich die Situation geändert hat, und eine hohe Karte nicht zum Zuge kommt. Billige Weltmarktpreise für Uran stechen in der Energieversorgungsdebatte nicht mehr, nach dem man den Ausstieg aus der Kernkraft beschlossen hat.